# Kivy: create a custom widget and do a new instance from kv

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to learn the Kivy api for a little project of mine, and I got stuck in this problem which I don't actually know if I'm approaching the right way.

I created a custom class, inheriting from Widget, with some things that I know I will be repeating a lot:

```py
#classes.py

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class TextField(Widget):
    field_id = ObjectProperty(None)
    field_text = StringProperty('Label: ')
    field_placeholder = StringProperty('your text here')

    grid = GridLayout(cols=2)
    label = Label(text=field_text)
    tinput = TextInput(id=field_id, text=field_placeholder)
    grid.add_widget(label)
    grid.add_widget(tinput)
```

Then I wanted to create the instance of my class in the kv file

```
#main.kv
<MainLayout>
    cols:3
    TextField:
        field_id:'someid'
        field_text:'My Label: '
        field_placeholder: 'My placeholder'
```

Now, the problem is that when I run it I get:

```
ValueError: Label.text accept only str
```

and when I print field_text, I get

```
<StringProperty name=>
```

So I guess it isn't a str, just like the error says. Did I just completely misunderstood properties? Is what I want to do possible in other way?

Thanks in advance for your time!

---

EDIT: The only thing that I can think of thats missing from my question to make it 100% reproducible is the entry point.

```py
#main.py
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from example.exampleapp import ExampleApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

```py
#exampleapp.py
from example.classes import *
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

with open('zapador/kv/main.kv', encoding='utf8') as f: 
    Builder.load_string(f.read())

class Mainlayout(GridLayout):
    pass

class ExampleApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Mainlayout()
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: the example already has all the characteristics described in there.

Comment: I have not asked for pieces of code but an MRE that allows me to analyze your problem quickly and easily, have you read the link that I have attached? If you don't do it then your question is probably closed for being off-topic. If it were an MRE then I would just have to make a copy-paste and execute it, but in the code it provides it does not meet that characteristic.

Comment: I seriously don't understand how the first exposition of the problem wasn't an MRE. I stripped the code to the minimum required to be reproducible, I added the result of the execution to explain how it is not working and what I expected to happen. If the problem is missing information, there, I added the entry point of the app.

Comment: When an MRE is requested, an example that is Minimal is requested: which is the easiest since it is to erase code, Reproducible: this is what failed in its initial code since its code did not allow me to reproduce its problem since although it seems silly Many times the error that causes the problem is in the part of code that does not show the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your code is the section of code in your `TextField` where it appears that you are trying to define the layout of your custom class:

```
grid = GridLayout(cols=2)
label = Label(text=field_text)
tinput = TextInput(id=field_id, text=field_placeholder)
grid.add_widget(label)
grid.add_widget(tinput)
```

If you are going to define the layout in python, you must do it inside a method, like inside the `__init__()` method. However, if you do that, then the `text` fields that you set in the `__init__()` method will be set to whatever the initial value of the `StringProperty` attribute is, and will not update if that `StringProperty` is changed (unless you add more code to handle that event and modify the associated `text` attribute).

A better, and simpler way, is to do the layout in `kv`, and let `kv` handle the updating the `text` attributes when the `StringProperty` is changed. So, I recommend changing your `TextField` class to:

```
#classes.py

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class TextField(Widget):
    field_id = ObjectProperty(None)
    field_text = StringProperty('Label: ')
    field_placeholder = StringProperty('your text here')
```

And define the layout in your `main.kv`:

```
#main.kv
<MainLayout>
    cols:3
    TextField:
        # field_id:'someid'
        field_text:'My Label: '
        field_placeholder: 'My placeholder'

<TextField>:
    field_id: ti
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: root.field_text
        TextInput:
            id: ti
            text: root.field_placeholder
```

With this arrangement, changes to your `StringProperty` will be reflected in the `text` attributes inside your `TextField`. Note that I have not used your `field_id` `ObjectProperty` as the `id` for the `TextInput`. I do not think it is possible to use an `ObjectProperty` as an `id`. I have used your `field_id` `ObjectProperty` as a reference to the `TextInput` inside the `TextField`